# c# .NET 2.0 zoom-scroll bar

Tags: c#, scroll, c#-2.0, zooming, charts

I am looking for a control that allows users to zoom and scroll at the same time. It basically needs to be something like Sony Sound Forge has, see bottom of this screenshot:
[image]

It looks and behaves like a normal scroll bar, with the addition that you can drag the edges to the left and right making the chart zoom in/out. Even if the user would be offered alternative ways to zoom in and scroll (e.g. by dragging an area on the chart itself) I still think such a component is useful because it gives the user a direct visual feedback of the position in the data and the amount of zooming that has been applied.

Does such a component exist or do I need to create it myself? Any help is welcome.

Comment: what controls do you use in that container?

Comment: I intend to use a graph display, very much like in the above screenshot. Does that answer your question? Because I don't think it is relevant. The zoom-scrollbar must simply give 2 float values between 0 and 1 for example, each time the user zooms or scrolls. These values represent the start and end positions of the bar.
(the above screenhsot is Sony Sound Forge, an audio editing tool from Sony, not from my own software)

Comment: I think you can solve this issue over your component, I think on each zoom you have to magnify your precision.

Comment: @lazycider: I don't think we're on the same wavelength here, at least I am not understanding your answer at all. I am looking for a UI control like in the one in the screenshot. The logic behind such a control is of course no rocket science. As I desceribed above, it should just return 2 values each time the user manipulates the control. I am just wondering if such a UI component exists at all. I could of course just create one myself, but to give it a consistent Windows look-and-feel that would be quite some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is very specific control and I don't think that it exists. Also I think it will be faster to create it by yourself, than search for it or even wait when someone answer this question.

To draw custom buttons like in **Sound Forge** you may use WinAPI function `DrawThemeBackground`.

I make some short example:

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly Int32 ScrollBarWidth;
    readonly Int32 ScrollBarHeight;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ScrollBarWidth  = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);
        ScrollBarHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYHSCROLL);
    }



    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 ZoomMarkerSize = 6;

        Graphics G      = e.Graphics;
        Int32 SBWidth   = ScrollBarWidth;
        Int32 SBHeight  = ScrollBarHeight;

        DrawCustomScrollButton(G, 0, 0, SBWidth, SBHeight, Resources.Plus,
            (int) SCROLLBARSTYLESTATES.SCRBS_NORMAL);
        DrawCustomScrollButton(G, SBWidth, 0, ZoomMarkerSize, SBHeight, null,
            (int) SCROLLBARSTYLESTATES.SCRBS_NORMAL);
        DrawCustomScrollButton(G, SBWidth + ZoomMarkerSize, 0, SBWidth, SBHeight, Resources.Minus,
            (int) SCROLLBARSTYLESTATES.SCRBS_HOT);
    }



    public void DrawCustomScrollButton (Graphics aG, Int32 aX, Int32 aY, Int32 aWidth, Int32 aHeight,
        Image aImage, Int32 aState)
    {
        RECT R = new RECT () { left = aX, top = aY, right = aX + aWidth, bottom = aY + aHeight };
        RECT NotUsed = R;

        IntPtr ThemeHandle  = OpenThemeData(this.Handle, "SCROLLBAR");
        IntPtr HDC          = aG.GetHdc();

        DrawThemeBackground
        (
            ThemeHandle, HDC,
            (int) SCROLLBARPARTS.SBP_THUMBBTNHORZ,
            aState,
            ref R, ref NotUsed
        );

        aG.ReleaseHdc(HDC);
        CloseThemeData(ThemeHandle);

        if (aImage != null)
        {
            aG.DrawImage(aImage,
                aX + ((ScrollBarHeight - aImage.Width   ) / 2),
                aY + ((ScrollBarHeight - aImage.Height  ) / 2));
        }
    }



    public struct RECT
    {
        public Int32 left; 
        public Int32 top; 
        public Int32 right; 
        public Int32 bottom; 
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int smIndex);

    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
    public extern static Int32 DrawThemeBackground(IntPtr hTheme, IntPtr hdc, int iPartId,
       int iStateId, ref RECT pRect, ref RECT pClipRect);

    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenThemeData(IntPtr hWnd, String classList);

    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
    public extern static Int32 CloseThemeData(IntPtr hTheme);

    public int SM_CYHSCROLL = 3;
    public int SM_CYVSCROLL = 20;

    public int SBP_ARROWBTN = 1;

    public int ABS_UPNORMAL = 1;
    public int ABS_UPHOT = 2;
    public int ABS_UPHOVER = 17;

    public enum ARROWBTNSTATES {
        ABS_UPNORMAL = 1,
        ABS_UPHOT = 2,
        ABS_UPPRESSED = 3,
        ABS_UPDISABLED = 4,
        ABS_DOWNNORMAL = 5,
        ABS_DOWNHOT = 6,
        ABS_DOWNPRESSED = 7,
        ABS_DOWNDISABLED = 8,
        ABS_LEFTNORMAL = 9,
        ABS_LEFTHOT = 10,
        ABS_LEFTPRESSED = 11,
        ABS_LEFTDISABLED = 12,
        ABS_RIGHTNORMAL = 13,
        ABS_RIGHTHOT = 14,
        ABS_RIGHTPRESSED = 15,
        ABS_RIGHTDISABLED = 16,
        ABS_UPHOVER = 17,
        ABS_DOWNHOVER = 18,
        ABS_LEFTHOVER = 19,
        ABS_RIGHTHOVER = 20,
    };

    public enum SCROLLBARSTYLESTATES {
        SCRBS_NORMAL = 1,
        SCRBS_HOT = 2,
        SCRBS_PRESSED = 3,
        SCRBS_DISABLED = 4,
        SCRBS_HOVER = 5,
    };

    public enum SCROLLBARPARTS {
        SBP_ARROWBTN = 1,
        SBP_THUMBBTNHORZ = 2,
        SBP_THUMBBTNVERT = 3,
        SBP_LOWERTRACKHORZ = 4,
        SBP_UPPERTRACKHORZ = 5,
        SBP_LOWERTRACKVERT = 6,
        SBP_UPPERTRACKVERT = 7,
        SBP_GRIPPERHORZ = 8,
        SBP_GRIPPERVERT = 9,
        SBP_SIZEBOX = 10,
    };
}
```

Here are form source files and two test PNG images for resources:
[scrollbar-with-zoom-example.zip](http://jojo.mechtoy.ru/stackoverflow.com/scrollbar-with-zoom-example.zip)

Check MSDN for additional info about this API and PINVOKE.NET site for function signatures.

**EDIT**

More better solution is to use `VisualStyleRenderer` class. Sorry for first complicate example. I did not know about that class before. So my `DrawCustomScrollButton` function should be replaced:

```
public void DrawCustomScrollButton (Graphics aG, Int32 aX, Int32 aY, Int32 aWidth, Int32 aHeight,
    Image aImage, Int32 aState)
{
    Rectangle R = new Rectangle(aX, aY, aX + aWidth, aY + aHeight);

    VisualStyleRenderer Renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer
    (
        VisualStyleElement.ScrollBar.ThumbButtonHorizontal.Normal
    );

    Renderer.DrawBackground(aG, R);

    if (aImage != null)
    {
        aG.DrawImage(aImage,
            aX + ((ScrollBarHeight - aImage.Width   ) / 2),
            aY + ((ScrollBarHeight - aImage.Height  ) / 2));
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Considering your comments, I made new try to recreate this custom control. Main idea was to use standart ScrollBar and put zoom markers above it (two Panel controls). It looks easy at first sight. But to combine these components together was more difficult than I thought.

The main problem is that difficult to alter behavior of system ScrollBar control. I found out that it does not allow to handle some events in windows message queue that I wanted to override. For example MouseUp event and some other.

In the end, I think the only right way is to recreate own copy of ScrollBar control from scratch in which will not have these constraints. Because of that, initially I went the wrong way and unfortunately did not solve your task.

Anyway here my current results (full solution):
[scrollbar-with-zoom-3.zip](http://jojo.mechtoy.ru/stackoverflow.com/scrollbar-with-zoom-3.zip)

Comment: I don't mind about the + and - buttons. I would in fact be happy with 2 buttons just having + and - as text put on them. They can be integrated with the scrollbar into a customcontrol. But that is not the main issue. The main issue is the scrollbar itself that must enable users to allow zooming as well as scrolling. Scrolling would be done like any normal scrollbar, zooming would done by dragging one side of the bar (or thumb as some call it) closer or furhter away from the other side of the bar.

Comment: If you look closely at the example you can see that the bar has 2 grippers on each side instead of just one in the middle like a normal scrollbar.

Comment: Now I see. In past I used an older version of this program and do not fully understood your question. Sadly that you dont do marks on screenshot what you need. Also I installed trial version of Sound Forge today and saw how new scrollbar working. So I will try to find more correct answer to your question later when I will have time. If I will success, I will make update.

Comment: Today I made new example, but it not completed and has some bugs. If you want to see my current results here my solution: [scrollbar-with-zoom-2.zip](http://jojo.mechtoy.ru/stackoverflow.com/scrollbar-with-zoom-2.zip)

Comment: Dmitry, that look absolutely splendid and is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your appreciation. Unfortunately, I not done your task completely. I put things in order in my solution, and has created custom control using UserControl class (see HScrollBarZ control). Some improvements has made but some problems still not solved. Anyway check download link in updated answer. Is there are ability to uncheck "accepted answer"? If yes, I think you should do that. May be someone will make more correct answer for you.